# Like Box without profile pic

Tags: facebook, profile, facebook-likebox

Want to implement the fb like box (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) in my own site. I've got some trouble 'bout the main pic of my page: I don't want it to be displayed in the stream, but only in the header.
I struggled to hide the pic but I didn't reach in troubleshotting.
Hope you can help me.
And sorry for bad english :P

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not an option of the like box plugin